# pathlib.Path with broken links

Tags: python, pathlib

I have been using `pathlib.Path` modules for some time now, as this is far more flexible and readable than `os.path`. I did not find a case not covered by `Path` until now.

I have a directory containing links pointing to a directory I have no access (I am not part of this group). For example:

```
> ls dir1
dir1/link1 -> /another_dir/file (No access)
```

The root directory (`p` object) contains several sub-directories, and broken links can be at various levels of the sub-tree.

I am trying to find these broken links and remove them. However I did not find a way to do it correctly:

- If I use `rglob`, the function only returns files and directories which are valid, so this code does not return the broken links:

  ```
  for f in p.rglob("*"):
     if not f.exists():
         print(f"{f} does not exist")
  ```
- If I use `iterdir()`, I have to do it recursively for each sub-directory, and on top of that `exists()` function triggers an exception (`PermissionError`) that I need to catch.

  ```
  >>> p = Path('dir1/link1')
  >>> p.is_symlink()
  True
  >>> p.exists()
  ...
  PermissionError: [errno 13] Permission Denied: 'dir1/link1'
  ```

So I think this is case for which I will go back to `os.walk` and `os.path.exists()` as this function returns `False` for broken links.

```
    for root, _, files in os.walk(str(p)):
        for f in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, f)
            if os.path.islink(filename) and not os.path.exists(filename):
                os.unlink(filename)
```

Any solution to use `pathlib` correctly here?

Comment: Have you checked Python's bug tracker? That exception thrown seems fishy to me on first thought.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, as the doc clearly describes that this is the expected behaviour on `exists()`. My point here is more that this is a case that is not so specific, and for which I don't see an obvious solution with the library.

Comment: Just use a general condition `p.is_symlink()` and then `try: p.exists()` and in case of a permission error, `p.unlink()`. This isn't such a beautiful control flow, but with a sentence or two of documentation it should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

So the best I can find with `pathlib` is the following, in line with the comments.

```
for dir in p.rglob("**/"):
    for filename in dir.iterdir():
        if filename.is_symlink():
            try:
                if not filename.exists():
                    print(f"{filename} is a broken link")
            except PermissionError:
                print(f"{filename} links to an file we cannot access")
```

The two `print` statements can be replaced by an action (Like `os.unlink`).

Although most of the time I prefer to use `pathlib` instead of `os.path`, in this case the `os.path` implementation is a lot easier to write:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(str(p)):
    for f in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.islink(filename) and not os.path.exists(filename):
            os.unlink(filename)
```